# ¿Como listar directorios que cumplan con un patrón de texto o expresión regular?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Buenos días, tardes o noches, he estado escribiendo un pequeño programa en `javascript`, mas específicamente `nodejs`, el cual se encarga de encontrar o leer ciertos archivos que se encuentran dentro de algunos directorios, algo así:

```
/raíz                               <------ directorio

    /directorio-uno-juan            <------ directorio
        /datos-personales.txt       <------ archivo
        /datos-laborales.txt        <------ archivo

    /directorio-dos-pedro           <------ directorio
        /datos-personales.txt       <------ archivo
        /datos-laborales.txt        <------ archivo

    /directorio-tres-pablo          <------ directorio
        /datos-personales.txt       <------ archivo
        /datos-laborales.txt        <------ archivo

    /directorio-cuatro-esteban      <------ directorio
        /datos-personales.txt       <------ archivo
        /datos-laborales.txt        <------ archivo
```

Cada directorio tiene un nombre unico, en el ejemplo que puse arriba para intentar mostrar la estructura que llevan los directorios y archivos, nombre a algunos directorios con el formato: `directorio-[numero]-[nombre]`, donde `[numero]` y `[nombre]` son valores variables, actualmente obtengo todos los directorios que se encuentran dentro de `/raiz` usando la función `fs.readdir` de `nodejs`, después recorro el arreglo de directorios con un bucle `for`, y entonces es cuando verifico si alguno de los directorios existe algún texto dado, el cual podría ser `numero` o `nombre`.

Uso el siguiente código:

```
const fs = require('fs'),

      //Defino el directorio que leeremos
      root_dir = 'raiz/',

      //Defino el texto a buscar, uso para ello process.argv[2], el
      //cual contiene el argumento pasado a través de la terminal,
      //ejemplo:   $ nodejs buscar_datos.js pablo
      name = process.argv[2];

//Ahora realizo el proceso antes mencionado:
fs.readdir(root_dir, (dirs) => {

    //Itero los directorios leidos:
    for(let i=0, dir; dir=dirs[i]; i++){

        //Ahora hago una búsqueda usando el método 'indexOf' de 'String' sobre el formato 'directorio-[numero]-[nombre]'
        if(dir.indexOf( name ) != -1){
            //Si el resultado de 'indexOf' es diferente a -1,
            //entonces hubo una búsqueda satisfactoria
            console.log('Se ha encontrado:', dir);
        }
    }
});
```

Me gustaría saber si existe alguna manera que me permita leer el directorio que necesito leer sin antes tener que listar todos los directorios y verificar de uno a uno si existe un texto dado en su nombre, algo como:

```
//Por ejemplo una expresión regular compuesta por un patrón formado
//por texto predefinido y texto ingresado por un usuario:
var reg = new RegExp('(raiz\/-uno-' + name + ')', 'ig');
fs.readdir( reg, (dirs) => { ... });
```

Agradeceré muchos sus respuesta y comentarios.

Answer (score 1):

Algo como comentas no es posible, pero podrias genera los nombres de archivos y su directorio que te interesan y luego preguntar si existen, algo como esto:

```
const fs = require('fs'),
      root_dir = 'raiz/directorio-',
      name = process.argv[2],
      prefix = ['uno', 'dos', 'tres'],
      files = prefix.map(function(x) { return root_dir+x+'-'+name}); //genera: ['raiz/directorio-uno-pablo', 'raiz/directorio-dos-pablo', 'raiz/directorio-tres-pablo']

const find = files.filter(function(f){ return fs.existsSync(f)}); // filter elimina los elementos de 'files' cuando no existe la carpeta.
console.log(find); // contiene un arreglo con los directorios que existen con el patron: 'raiz/directorio-[prefix]-[name]'
```